# jmeter connectivity issue with oracle

Tags: database, oracle, testing, jmeter, connectivity

> Response message: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create
>   PoolableConnectionFactory (ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL
>   level 1 ORA-12705: Cannot access NLS data files or invalid environment
>   specified )

Answer (score 0):

Follow this procedure to set the NLS_LANG environment variable for Oracle databases. To set the NLS_LANG environment variable for Oracle databases Determine the NLS_LANG value. In the data warehouse database, run the command SELECT * FROM V$NLS_PARAMETERS

Make a note of the NLS_LANG value, which is in the format [NLS_LANGUAGE]_[NLS_TERRITORY].[NLS_CHARACTERSET]. For example: American_America.UTF8 For Windows: Navigate to Control Panel > System and click the Advanced tab. Click Environment Variables. In System variables section, click New. In the Variable Name field, enter NLS_LANG. In the Variable Value field, enter the NLS_LANG value that was returned in Step 1. The format for the NLS_LANG value should be [NLS_LANGUAGE]_[NLS_TERRITORY].[NLS_CHARACTERSET]. For example: American_America.UTF8. For UNIX, set the variable as shown below: setenv NLS_LANG

For example: setenv NLS_LANG American_America.UTF8. If your data is 7-bit or 8-bit ASCII and the Informatica Server is running on UNIX, then set NLS_LANG _.WE8ISO8859P1 CAUTION: Make sure you set the NLS_LANG variable correctly, as stated in this procedure, or your data will not display correctly.

Reboot the machine after creating the variable.

validation query should change to "select 1 from dual" in jmeter in JDBC CONNECTION CONFIGURATION.

dont put semicolon ; at the end of your query in JDBC REQUEST

Answer (score 0):

I have just had this problem when upgrading from JMeter 3.2 to 4.0.

My previously working scripts would not work and I received the error mentioned above.

I did not have the option to go and change the NLS_LANG environment variable for Oracle databases.

My solution as to simply change JMeter.bat and **NOT** pass the JMETER_LANGUAGE

i.e. in JMeter.bat:

```
if not defined JMETER_COMPLETE_ARGS (
    rem set ARGS=%JAVA9_OPTS% %DUMP% %HEAP% %VERBOSE_GC% %GC_ALGO% %DDRAW% %SYSTEM_PROPS% %JMETER_LANGUAGE% %RUN_IN_DOCKER%
    set ARGS=%JAVA9_OPTS% %DUMP% %HEAP% %VERBOSE_GC% %GC_ALGO% %DDRAW% %SYSTEM_PROPS% %RUN_IN_DOCKER%
) else (
    set ARGS=
)
```